# Unable to get response from http request from a localhost API (node js express) on Flutter Web

Tags: node.js, flutter, flutter-web, flutter-http

i build a simple api that has a response body of
`{ "name": "saud", "age": "22" }`

it is hosted on `http://localhost:7283/saud` using Node js express

`app.get('/saud',(req,res)=>{res.status(200).send({name:'saud',age:'22'}) } );`

it works if i access from a **(physical mobile/Insomnia/Chrome)** but when i host my **Web app** on **localhost** and the request is sent.
i keep getting CircularProgressIndicator (meaning that there is no response in future)

this is my code for flutter:

```
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: FutureBuilder<http.Response>(
        future: getUrl(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            print(json.decode(snapshot.data!.body));
            return Text(json.decode(snapshot.data!.body).toString());
          }
          return CircularProgressIndicator();
        },
      )),
    );
  }

Future<http.Response> getUrl() async {
        return http.get(Uri.parse('http://192.168.92.226:7283/saud/'));
      }
```

this exact same code is working perfectly for mobile app or insomnia

[insomnia](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aUGHk.png)
[poco x3 pro](https://i.stack.imgur.com/INkRz.jpg)

[network tab dev tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4EMU1.png)

Comment: Could you please show the request in the network tab of the developer tools ?
It could be a cors problem or something like this.

Comment: @jeremynac attached a screenshot in the OP

Comment: @jeremynac it is a cors problem the red button on top left shows this: Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://192.168.92.226:7283/saud/' from origin 'http://localhost:62894' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Answer (score 0):

The "CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'" error means that the backend is blocking your frontend request because it's running on http://localhost on a different port than the backend port.
To fix it, just use the cors package on the backend:

```
app.use(cors({
    origin: '*'
}));
```

If not working:

```
app.use(cors({
    origin: 'http://localhost:<yourFlutterWebPort>'
}));
```

If it's still not working, your might consider using a proxy or a http-tunnel like [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/)